# Where can I find regional SO toppers?

Tags: feature-request, users, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to find Stack Overflow users based on an area?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60876/is-there-a-way-to-find-stack-overflow-users-based-on-an-area)

Where can I find the list of top 10 users by region or country category?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a [Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I just ran a StackQL query, and the results (Reputation, LastAccessDate) seem to be as of some time back in October 2009.  Oh, never mind.  "Online SQL Management Studio for the StackOverflow Community Dataset (currently hosting the October 2009 release)."  Anyway, it's a good tool, as long as you don't require up-to-the-minute accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Location field at user profile is a freetext field, so I think it's difficult to get a clear result.

Comment: Should I be more specific about my address?

Comment: Why? It's rather clear. I think you top your region.

Answer (score -1):

[careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) if you're looking to hire.