# Finding Stack Overflow/Exchange users based on geographic area?

Tags: support, community, location

I want to find Stack Overflow/Exchange users in my area.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be built in functionality, maybe someone on stackapp's has done it?

Comment: related: [Social events for stack overflow users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60262/social-events-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: What will you do once you find them?  Should they be concerned?

Comment: Such facility is not provided

Comment: Related: **[Top Users from All World Countries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1250968/top-reputation-users-from-all-countries-of-the-world)**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) (SEDE) and create a query against the `Location`-Field of the `Users`-Table. Such a query [already exists](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/130918/top-users-by-location). However, this is a very limited possibility, but maybe it's enough. It also depends on the users themselfes; if they haven't entered their location, you can't find them.

The only other possibility I see, is to get the IP address of each user. With that you can find really everyone, but that's not an option. It is also not reliable; if the user is accessing the site via a proxy or from within a corporate network, it could very well be an IP address from a completely different country.

Comment: are there any tutorials on how to use that tool anywhere?

Comment: @Micah: It's just SQL...I can compile you such a query if you want to.

Comment: That would be great! Then I can at least get an idea of how it works.

Comment: @Micah: Well, somebody did it before me: http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/s/162/list-of-users-in-a-given-location

Comment: Well, even if you could find everyone's IP: according to IP geolocation, I'm in Norway (not). Proxies and VPNs and tunnels, oh my!

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby - Have you an answer for [my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193641/231637)?

Answer (score 3):

Although someone suggested using the location field and the data explorer, that's not good enough.

For example, my location is currently "Rome, New York, United States". First off, there are variants as to specificity (some people only put a country or state). Second, if I were to do a search for Rome, I would get false positives (Rome, Georgia, United States and Rome, Italy) come to mind. I would also miss locations near my - Buffalo, Rochester, Syracuse, Utica, Albany - no one in those towns would show up unless I made my search queries very complicated.

Stack Overflow should work on adding geolocation to your profiles so you can search by users who are within 100 miles of your location, for example.

Answer (score 1):

For SO, and SO only, you can do so effectively on [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/candidate-search). You can't see *who's* in each geographical area without an invite and paying for access, but it still makes for fun browsing.