# Can I find out how many people of my country is on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to find stackoverflow users based on an area?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60876/is-there-a-way-to-find-stackoverflow-users-based-on-an-area)

Is there any searching criteria by which I can search people of my country having more than 10000 reputation or having 10 gold badges, etc.?

Comment: if you were going to use the "Location" field on the profiles, you can enter anything you want...

Comment: What i want that www.stackoverflow.com/users/uk

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60876/is-there-a-way-to-find-stackoverflow-users-based-on-an-area