# Looking for users in my region

Tags: discussion, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to find Stack Overflow users based on an area?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60876/is-there-a-way-to-find-stack-overflow-users-based-on-an-area)

I would like to meet up with other Stackoverflow enthusiasts in my region, Boulder CO. I see posts from 2009 about finding members using statoverflow, but that site does not exist today in 2011.

Is there any way to find other users in my area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those queries can be made on the http://data.stackexchange.com (which I think replaced the statoverflow).  [Here's](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/302/find-stack-overflow-users-in-your-city-with-user-links) an example query.  Searching the site for "country" yields a few more options, and you could always write your own query.