# Query for users with highest reputation by location?

Tags: discussion, meta, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to find Stack Overflow users based on an area?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60876/is-there-a-way-to-find-stack-overflow-users-based-on-an-area)

I know this is a duplicate but I've tried searching and can't find the question. At some point there was a query you could do with the API that showed what the users with the highest reputation is based on their specified location. Can someone help me find that query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you're looking for [List of Users in a given location](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/162/list-of-users-in-a-given-location)
.

Here's a sample of [the results for "New Zealand"](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/162/list-of-users-in-a-given-location?location=New+Zealand).

```
User Link                    location                                 reputation 
---------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------- 
Greg Hewgill                 Christchurch, New Zealand                162914    
1800 INFORMATION             Auckland, New Zealand                    31455     
Orion Edwards                New Zealand                              27968     
Richard aka cyberkiwi        New Zealand                              24877     
Preet Sangha                 Auckland, New Zealand                    21590     
Kent Fredric                 New Zealand                              20194     
slugster                     New Zealand                              14536     
Bevan                        Wellington, New Zealand                  13610     
Marko                        Auckland, New Zealand                    10489     
Nat                          New Zealand                              8421
```

Comment: That results from that query are rather dubious (non existant when I enter *New Zealand* which is where I a from).

Comment: @slugster Did you capitalize it? I get 1205 rows; you're #7

Comment: Ahhh, ok - I tried lowercase & proper case, never realised it had to be uppercase. I guess I'm too used to doing case and collation insensitive text searches, that will teach me.