# Advanced Search In Users tab?

Tags: feature-request, users, search

Question raised because I read blog https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/. And I would like to see users in my area. I may contact them by email if they given email id in their profile.

Is there any possibility to have advanced search for users tab?

1. Location
2. Country
3. Age
4. Reputation range
5. Specific tags
6. Visited(No. of days)
7. Member for

Pardon me, if you feel not community helping feature.

## Update:

I really don't wanted to have feature which is not community worth feature. Only able to find people which are near me. But many people on sister sites like history, physics, biology, art, etc. may not understand queries. That's why I have posted question. There can be easy way to find this.

If we are able to find from https://data.stackexchange.com/, then why should there be easy way to find or not?

Comment: At least with regard to location, this **can** be searched.  See [Bolt's query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/27163/top-users-singapore) - you can modify it to your country...

Comment: I don't think `feature-discussion` is really needed as a tag. Every feature request come with its own discussion anyway. Not going to remove the tag, leaving this for someone more qualified.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Agreed, and changed.

Comment: Feature discussion can be old(existing) or new(required). That's why added tag.

Comment: @Lix: Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk That's why the system shows a date when something was posted. No need to create a new tag unnecessarily when the system as been working without it for more then 3 years.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk we can also tag a question here as both `feature-request` and `discussion` if it's really needed.

Comment: @Lix: Stole your idea and edited into my post: http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/65967/top-users-pune Hope you don't mind

Comment: @sha - [I'm number 4 on MSO in Israel :P You're leading the pack :P](http://i.imgur.com/XrVdI.png) but the numbers are a bit whacky :S

Comment: @Lix the data is old (couple of months I think) but still, feels good! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find Stack Overflow users based on an area?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60876/is-there-a-way-to-find-stack-overflow-users-based-on-an-area)

Comment: @Somnath the data explorer works and is easy (I made the query for you), why do you need to complicate the SO system?

Comment: The data explorer is precisely for such localised stuff--no need for a new feature every time.

Answer (score 8):

To find users near you, use [the meetup page](http://www.meetup.com/stackoverflow/).

Email ids are not publicly displayed, and that's not going to change anytime soon. Only diamond mods can privately contact users (I think this is disable-able); and that too without their email id being displayed.

I don't see how an an advanced search is beneficial to SO. We're not Facebook (though MSO may look like it). The only beneficial point I see is for meetups--and for that, the meetup page exists already. Though a way to advertise to other users would be good for this, it could snowball into spam. Better to stay away from that.

EDIT: Or, as @Lix suggested, run [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65967/top-users-pune) on whichever site you wish ;)

**[Here's a general query with an inputbox for location](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66100/top-users-of-a-particular-location)**

Comment: MSO looks like Facebook?

Comment: I was also feeling it's not community worth feature though I have added question. That's one reason I wanted to have advanced search.

Comment: @Lix: At first glance, yes. A whole bunch of people doing pointless things and talking about waffles--Not so different from FB, IMO Though they don't have anything as awesome as waffles ;). After joining the community, though, its different. That's why I said it _looks_ like FB.

Comment: I guess you have a point... (* POKE *)

Comment: I think active people on SO and MSO are anti-facebook.:-)

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: Edit: see this: http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/65967/top-users-pune

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: Whoops, wrong link: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65967/top-users-pune

Answer (score 2):

Our friendly neighborhood moderator, [Bolt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137537/boltclock) has [written a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/27163/top-users-singapore) with the data explorer that will solve (IMO) the most interesting detail that you mentioned of a users profile.  **The location**.

The query can be modified to search for users in any location - as I have demonstrated below.  This modified query will return all users who have listed Israel as their location.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS [#], 
    Id AS [User Link], 
    Reputation
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    LOWER(Location) LIKE '%israel%'
ORDER BY
    Reputation DESC;
```

Further customization of this query could give you more details -
for example -

- Select users by **age and location**

```
...
WHERE
    Age LIKE '18' AND
    LOWER(Location) LIKE '%israel%'
...
```

- Select users within a **reputation range**

```
...
WHERE
    Reputation > '1000' AND 
    Reputation < '10000'
...
```

Might not be the most efficient way to get this info - but you *can* get to some of the details you are looking for...

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/65967/top-users-pune Already modified

Comment: I haven't used the data explorer much - how about making the country and country code's variables so that any user can come along and use the query to find information about their own country?

Comment: Its better not to change `SG` to `IN`--Singapore is a city-country-thingy. Anyone in the country is nearby. Not so for India

Comment: India's pretty large.. I'll make a general one, though

Comment: That query explains so much at so many levels.....

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65968/top-users-mumbai http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65970/top-users-india Here you go.

Comment: @Diago: I didn't quite get you :/

Comment: @ManishEarth There is probably only about 0.00001% of SE that would, but I decided to leave it anyway for the minuscule chance that someone else can make the link.