# Data explorer doesn't like me

Tags: support, data-explorer

I made a few DE queries for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128269/advanced-search-in-users-tab)

Anyways, I was testing the queries, and I noticed that it doesn't catch me in these queries:

1. https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/65968/top-users-mumbai
2. https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/65970/top-users-india

Even though it is `ORDER BY Reputation DESC`, and (not to boast), I have more rep on Physics.SE than any of them-- I should be displayed in the results.

It may be an issue with my SQL, I've never really formally learned SQL and I'm used to testing out queries on a command line.

Or, it may be a caching issue--I entered my location a week back. (a week seems a bit long for a cache, though--or do you use dumps?)

Comment: DE uses dumps as far as I recall, and is normally quite behind the actual data. Query the users table for you and check if the field is populated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SEDE data are updated roughly every three months. On the [front page](https://data.stackexchange.com/) the date of the last update is shown at the far right, for each site, they are usually updated on the same day or a day apart.

For Physics the most recent update was on March 15, so SEDE doesn't know your location (yet).