# Stack Exchange users on a map

Tags: feature-request, support, api

I am interested in putting together a map of the locations of all Stack Overflow users worldwide (perhaps with a minimum score of 100), obviously contingent on them having filled in the location field.

I'm mainly interested in setting something like this up, because I think it would be very useful when making decisions about moving to a particular new location. For instance, I live in the UK and would love, in a few years time, to live somewhere by the sea or by the mountains. But in such areas companies are often small, recruit infrequently and are hard to find.

Knowing that in small town X there were four or five great developers in my language of choice would go a long way to encouraging me to have a look into that area in more detail and would in general narrow down the search.

I've found [StackMaps](http://johndbritton.com/stackmaps/), but although very nice, it doesn't have a comprehensive database of all the users (I believe it samples a few pages from the top users via the API). I would be aiming to have everyone who has registered their location.

My question is: I can scrape this information in via the API (making sure I stay within the daily limit), and am happy to do so. I know there is a daily limit of 10k requests - but am I sticking to the spirit of the agreement if I do 10k requests continuously for a couple of weeks? And if not, is there a better way to accomplish what I need (I've looked at the database dumps, but they don't have user location).

Many thanks, and if something like this already exists - please let me know!

Comment: Just to get you started: There's at least one great developer in Thessaloniki, Greece.

Comment: Maybe duplicate? [Is there a way to find Stack Overflow users based on an area?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60876/is-there-a-way-to-find-stack-overflow-users-based-on-an-area)

Comment: You could use [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) as a first step, that would get you most of the way there (except for the `WHERE LIVES BY THE SEA` clause :)