# Finding specific users by their location and a tag score

Tags: support, data-explorer, users, tag-score, location

I want to see who has the highest score in a specific tag (for example `c#`) in my country.

Is there any query or script for that?

I've found [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/125081/talent-search-based-on-location-and-tags), but it doesn't work. Can any one take a look at it and see what's its problem?

I also have found [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/130926) which does similar, however gets users which only have a tag badge.

Comment: just for curiousity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Damien - One of them is quickly finding real pros near my area. Maybe we become co-workers in a project...

Comment: I am not sure how you would make contact with them considering many use pseudonyms, often do not have their contact details showing and remembering that there is no private messaging (thankfully) on any SE site.

Comment: Unless you're looking to *hire* people (http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), you have no reason to be doing this. Stalking people is unethical, and probably illegal.

Comment: @CodyGray - No, I'm just interested in examining myself in a tag with other users in my area... Is it illegal...?!

Comment: The only real way to do that would be to pick a tag, say [tag:asp.net], and then check out the list of [top users for that tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net/topusers). You'll have to look at each person's profile to see where they're from, but that's about all you *can* do, since listing a location is optional. And lying is acceptable.

Comment: @CodyGray "and lying is acceptable." Gads, you mean I haven't be *obfuscating* all along? Fake real name ->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining the score of a group of users in a tag is relatively easy because that only requires a sum of the score field per post per user. This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382658/finding-specific-users-by-their-location-and-a-tag-score?tag1=Haskell&location=India) does exactly that:

```sql
select u.id as [User Link]
     , sum(score) as totalscore
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id 
                       or pt.postid = p.parentid
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
where tagname = ##tag1:string## collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI 
and location like '%'+ ##location:string## + '%'  collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI 
group by u.id
order by sum(score) desc
```

To get an approximate reputation you need to join with the votes table and then this becomes more complex quickly.

Do notice that location is a user maintained field, there is no guarantee the user is near that [Location](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382658/finding-specific-users-by-their-location-and-a-tag-score?tag1=c&location=Location) at all.